# Permutation modules and tensor products

Tags: modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

I am studying how permutation modules behave wrt tensor products, and I have the following, maybe trivial, question:

Suppose that $V,W$ are, respectively, finitely generated $RG,RH$ modules; assume that $G,H$ are finite groups and R a field, algebraically closed. Consider the tensor product $V\otimes_R W$, as a $G\times H$ module, where $(g,h)(v\otimes w)=(gv)\otimes(hw)$.

Now if $V$ and $W$ are permutation modules, then certainly $V\otimes W$ is a permutation module.

Does also the opposite hold? If $V\otimes W$ is a permutation modules, then both or at least one of the modules $V,W$ must be a permutation module?

Comment: Cool question. I don't know the answer but for what it's worth the Burnside ring commutes with products.

Comment: Follow-up remark: Start with a permutation representation, which we view as an element $\gamma \in A(G \times H)$. As Burnside rings commute with products, it corresponds to a product $(\gamma_1,\gamma_2) \in A(G) \times A(H)$. When are these realizable by actual representations? In the representation ring, one can do this by taking inner products with orthonormal basis elements and checking if this yields nonnegative integers. (cont.)

Comment: Since $\gamma$ comes from a representation, this will probably be the case provided that the isomorphisms $R_{\mathbb{C}}(G \times H) \cong R_{\mathbb{C}}(G) \otimes R_{\mathbb{C}}(H)$ is compatible with inner products, which I suspect is true.